# setSrc not working to fix broken audio player

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I have an audio player that gets initialized on my WordPress page. Unfortunately, sometimes the audio url is not valid (maybe even blank). I tried fixing it by calling `mejs.players[0].setSrc('working.mp3');`
but it is throwing `TypeError: this.media.setSrc is not a function`

I tried setting the media.src then load(), but that didn't work either. It has made a div with class 'me-cannotplay'. Does this mean that this player cannot be used?

Any way to still use this player?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add "flashmediaelement.swf"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
<audio id="player" controls="controls">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src=""/>
</audio>
```

then

```js
player.setSrc([{ "type": "audio/mp3", "src": "some/url.mp3" }]);
```